# Raytracer in occupancy_grid_utils

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear Ros Users,
I am trying to perform a raytracing from a pointcloud in my node. The aim is to have a result similar to the one provided by octomap_server, but in my node.

I tried to occupancy_grid_utils package in ros_indigo, but it seems that raytracing is not well performed, in particular it seems that rays are "cutted" before the end point

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/231042/raytracer-in-occupancy_grid_utils/) by [Rahndall](https://answers.ros.org/users/3415/rahndall/) on ROS Answers with karma: 133 on 2016-04-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I think that raytracer is for 2D and not for 3D.

Best,

---

Originally posted by [andrestoga](https://answers.ros.org/users/21535/andrestoga/) with karma: 188 on 2017-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0